# How to send view data to another view in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, include

I create "bulten" view. And I want to add "bulten" to somewhere in "anasayfa" view.

I use -> 
`$this->load->view("bulten");` in a view and work. Is it right solution way?

Because I saw it https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html?highlight=view but I don't understand it.

I tried it and did not work ->

**anasayfa controller ->**

```
    public function index()
    {
            $data['bulten'] = $this->load->view("bulten");
            $this->load->view('anasayfa', $data);
    }
```

anasayfa view I called it ->
$bulten;
Where is wrong? Can someone explane it?

Comment: You can load a view from a view, no need to do it from controller. just add in your view anasayfa.php this line: `<?php $this->load->view("bulten") ?>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to return the html of a view you should use view functions 3rd parameter true. See [returning-view-as-data](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#returning-views-as-data)

In your case it should be like this

```
$data['bulten'] = $this->load->view("bulten",'',true);
```